# getting the wrong version of python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, path-variables

I have installed python 3.6 on my laptop but when I run the version command I get the 2.7 version. I have changed the path variable and still get the same result and the funny thing is that I don't even have python 2.7 installed on my laptop.

here is the image [path variable and version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98d0U.png) also when I run python in cmd I get the error [run error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXz2f.png) any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Type `where -a python` to see in what order the command `python` is found on your path.

Comment: Thanks mate that solved the issue :)

Comment: Great. Made it an answer to make it more useful for others and allowing you to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer. ;)

Comment: Use `python3.6` as the full command.

Comment: Do not post images of text. Just copy the exact text in your post.

Comment: sure sure next time you will get the text only :)

Comment: Why not start here? There is an [edit] button under the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing:

```
where -a python
```

shows you the order in which the command

```
python
```

is found on your path.

Use:

```
which -a python
```

on unix-like systems such as Linux or MacOS X.