# Showing python 2.7.12 for python 3.9.1 on Command window?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I am using python 3.9.1 on my computer and when I try this command on cmommand windows : python -- version , I come up with 2.7.12 !!! And it does not show the version correct.
I uninstalled python and removed all the related files on C drive as well as environmental Variables...
Now I don't have python but it still shows the version 2.7.12 when I ask for Command windows!!!
Does anyone know what is the problem ????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting the wrong version of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474529/getting-the-wrong-version-of-python)

Comment: Yes exactly the same , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have both versions then you should write `python2 --version` o

Answer (score 2):

Go to my computer, right click and then properties. Here go to Advanced System setting
and at the bottom of the window open Environment Variables and check any variable having python on it. if there are two variable maybes this is the problem.
Also go to the app data on your windows and check files if there is a file related to the older version of  python.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell instead of cmd as well try this one after checking the variables.